# How to get the default image of Wikipedia article?

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is it possible to get the (default) image associated with a Wikipedia article with an API call if only the URL of the article is known?

Is it possible to make constraints about the image size / resolution in the call (as an image is usually available in different resolutions)?

Is it possible to request the largest image version not larger than `MAX_X` px?

**An example:**

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Jaguar_%28Panthera_onca_palustris%29_female_Piquiri_River_2.JPG

is `4769x3179` large (1,5 ratio).

A request limiting the `MAX_X` size to `3000` would result in an image scaled to `3000x2000`.

A request limiting the `MAX_X` size to `5000` would result in the image of the original size (`4769x3179`) because `MAX_X` is bigger than the image's x size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageimages) with **pageimages**. For example for Wikipedia article [Jaguar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaguar) and requested max image size **500** the query will be:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=Jaguar&pithumbsize=500
```

From the response you can get also [the largest image version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Junior-Jaguar-Belize-Zoo.jpg), just remove the **thumb** part and everything from **the pixels to the end** of the link.

Comment: Is it possible to request the largest image version && not larger than MAX_X px? e.g. img is 2000x1000, reguest is largest && not larger than 1. MAX_X=1000 > response img with 1000x500 - 2. MAX_X=4000 > response img with 2000x1000

Comment: @B.Smith yes, you can by using this API, just set `pithumbsize=MAX_X` and the response will include always **the largest image version && not larger than MAX_X px**.